# Join 2 items from an Array and add it as Item in the same array

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I have this Array of items. The problem is I need to join the `CertificateNumber` and `Ordinal` from all the items and add a new value for each.

So I can have `CertificateJoin: AAAAA00`

AAAAA is the `CertificateNumber` and 00 is the `Ordinal`

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Please read the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions, particularly on using [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) and [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cycle through your array and put your merged value in a new property, like so:

```js
var items = [{
    fieldA: 1,
    fieldB: "A"
  },
  {
    fieldA: 2,
    fieldB: "B"
  }
]

items.forEach(item => item["join"] = item.fieldA + item.fieldB);

console.log(items);
```